# Bug in Apache Commons StringEscapeUtil?

Tags: java, html, apache-commons

Just started using Apache Commons [`StringEscapeUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-3.0-beta/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html).

According to http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_entities.asp, `&Ouml;` should correspond to Ö. However,

```
System.out.println(StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4("&Ouml;"));
```

prints

```
×
```

Is this a bug? Or what am I missing?

Comment: Where does it print that? On the console?

Comment: No, on the printer... jk, yes, in the console.

Comment: Can your console display `Ö`?

Comment: Are you using the 3.0 beta version?

Comment: Yes. 3.0 beta, so the question is, is it a bug in this beta version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

version 2.5 `StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml` prints `Ö`

version 3.0-beta `StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml3` and `StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4` print `×`

Generally I'd use the latest stable version (currently 2.5). Looks like a bug but I couldn't find anything useful in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LANG

Comment: Confirmed. 2.5 works. Bug in the beta I suppose. Thanks cherouvim!

Comment: Issue was adressed in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LANG-658

Answer (score 6):

I guess [EntityArrays.java](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/commons/proper/lang/trunk/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/lang3/text/translate/EntityArrays.java?view=markup) from the lang3 repository is buggy:

```
{"\u00D6", "&Otilde;"}, // � - uppercase O, tilde
{"\u00D7", "&Ouml;"}, // � - uppercase O, umlaut
{"\u00D8", "&times;"}, // multiplication sign
```

It seems, that some values are shifted by one row. It must be:

```
 {"\u00D6", "&Ouml;"}, // � - uppercase O, umlaut
 {"\u00D7", "&times;"}, // multiplication sign
```

because `Ö` is `00D6` according to [LATIN CAPITAL LETTER O WITH DIAERESIS](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00d6/index.htm)

and `x` is `"\u00D7"`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your console cannot show the Ö character. Check the system property `file.encoding` to see what the default console encoding is.

If your console supports UTF-8 you can try to start the JVM with `-Dfile.encoding=utf-8`, or you can do this from your application:

```
System.setOut(new PrintStream(System.out, true, "utf-8"));
```

If the console does not support UTF-8, I suggest to try to write that to a file instead, using UTF-8 encoding, then open the file with a text editor that can handle UTF-8.

If all of this doesn't work, then it is probably a bug in `StringEscapeUtils`.

Comment: The console printed `ö` for `&ouml;` so this was probably not the problem.